# Where is my collected data after 30 minutes on inactivity in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I'm writing an app in React and I want to add Google Analytics to can see where are people getting stuck.

My app is collecting data correctly, but after 30 minutes all my collected data is gone and the average duration of the interaction is not changing.

I need to wait 24 hours to can see all the dashboards updated or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9333790?hl=en#:~:text=Many%20of%20your%20reports%20and,from%20your%20website%20or%20app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait 48/72 hours before seeing stable data in the GA4 platform.

Comment: It's up to 48. You never need more than 48.

Comment: I found data that settled after 72h, moreover it is the Google documentation that says it, it would be enough to read it: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9964640?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: You are misreading the documentation and no, you couldn't find the data settling after 72h. 72h is the time window for late hits. Late because of your delay, not Google's. And you don't have that delay unless you implement it. I've ran enough GA4 ETL to know there are no rogue events after 48h. This is the piece of documentation you should be looking at for it: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9333790?hl=en#:~:text=Many%20of%20your%20reports%20and,from%20your%20website%20or%20app

Comment: I talk about stable data (not just data), because events could be processed if they arrive up to 72 hours late. In the case of the question it may have been necessary to specify, but that became another post. Anyway I saw the data settle down after 48h, furthermore (for example) I set also Analytics large enough to see that modeling also goes into crisis and doesn't settle down with thousands of users per day (it's not in the documentation, even Google support is still understanding why). Just to say that we are talking about particular cases and the platform has yet to do some adjustments.